# How do i get my Linked List to work with my java fx table

Tags: java, javafx, linked-list

Fixed the code to make it work. I'm having problems with adding and the observable arraylist in the Table Controller class. I'm not sure if i have the Property Model right so i can use the methods from the linked list

Main class

```
import javafx.application.Application;


import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TableScreen.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("TableView Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 700));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Generic Interface

```
public interface GenericInterface<T> {

    public boolean add(T newEntry);
    public void add(int index, T newEntry);


}
```

PropertlyList

```
 public class PropertyList<T> implements GenericInterface<T>
    {

        // public static Object Node;
        private Node<T> startOfList;
        private int length;

        /**
         *
         */
        public PropertyList() {
            startOfList = null;
            length = 0;
        }

        public boolean add(T newEntry) {
            Node temp = startOfList;
            startOfList = new Node((T)newEntry, temp);
            length++;
            return true;
        }

        public void add(int index, T newEntry) {
            Node previous = startOfList;
            Node current = startOfList;

            if(index < 0 || index > length){   //invalid index
                return;// false;
            }
            if(index == 0){
                add(newEntry);
                return;
            }
            int positionInList = 1; //second node in list
            current=current.next; //current moved on to next item

            while (current != null && positionInList < index) {
                positionInList++;
                current = current.next;
                previous = previous.next;
            }

            if (positionInList == index) {
                Node temp = new Node((T) newEntry, current);
                previous.next = temp;
                length++;
                return;
            }
            return;
        }

        /*******************************************************************************/
        class Node<T1> {  //inner class
            private T1 myData; // this is a piece of primitive data as a textbook type example
            private Node next;

            private Node(T1 newData, Node newNext) {
                myData = newData;
                next = newNext;
            }
        }
        /*******************************************************************************/

    }
```

PropertyModel

```
public class PropertyModel {






    PropertyList propertyList = new PropertyList();

    public PropertyList getPropertyList() {
        return propertyList;
    }

    public void addProp(int id,String desc ){


        Property property = new Property(id,desc);

        propertyList.add(property);


    }


}
```

TableController

```
import com.sun.javafx.menu.MenuItemBase;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class TableController implements Initializable {
    PropertyModel properties;


    @FXML
    private TableView tblView;
    @FXML
    public TableView tblView_2;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Property, String> columnId;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Property, String> descriptionColumn;


    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Property, String> ratingColumn;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtId;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtdesc;


    ObservableList<String> categories = FXCollections.observableArrayList("All", "Attached", "Semi-Attached");
    ObservableList<String> subCategories = FXCollections.observableArrayList("All", "Waterford", "Cork", "Dublin");
    @FXML
    private MenuItemBase detailedProductViewButton;


    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        properties = new PropertyModel();  // initialise shop to a new (empty) collection of Products

        // for test purposes -- add a few products

        properties.addProp(1, "ok" );


        ObservableList<PropertyList> data =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(properties.getPropertyList());

        columnId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Property, String>("id"));
        descriptionColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Property, String>("address"));
tblView.setItems(data);
    }


    public void AddButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) {


            int id = Integer.parseInt(txtId.getText());

            String desc = txtdesc.getText();




        }
    }
```

Table screen FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="509.0" prefWidth="697.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="TableController">
    <children>
        <Pane prefHeight="509.0" prefWidth="697.0">
            <children>
                <TableView fx:id="tblView" layoutX="161.0" layoutY="7.0" prefHeight="274.0" prefWidth="376.0">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="columnId" prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="descriptionColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Description" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
                <TextField fx:id="txtId" layoutX="61.0" layoutY="291.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="86.0" />
                <TextField fx:id="txtdesc" layoutX="236.0" layoutY="291.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="86.0" />
                <Label layoutX="31.0" layoutY="295.0" text="ID" />
                <Label layoutX="167.0" layoutY="295.0" text="Description" />
            <Button layoutX="431.0" layoutY="291.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#AddButton" text="Add" />
            </children>
        </Pane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Property Class

```
public class Property {

    private int id;
    private String address;

    public Property(int id, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: ok done i added more.

Comment: There is no type `PropertyList propertyList = new PropertyList();`

Comment: There are many compile errors with what you have provided, cannot reproduce.

Comment: Ok sorry about that give me a few minutes ill shorten it and fix it to show what i need.

Comment: If you do provide a full working example of your code (or just the full code in general) I'll take a look at it within an hour or so.

Comment: Ok i fixed it up and it should be working now

Comment: In general, I wouldn't recommend creating your own linked list class in Java beyond a learning exercise.  Java already has a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) class which you can use without creating your own class.  One advantage of the built-in implementation is that it implements the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) interface, so you can just do `tblView.getItems().setAll(data);` where data is the `LinkedList`.

Comment: Also, if you want the TableView to dynamically respond to changes and auto-update your list, then instead of using a LinkedList, you can use an ObservableList, if you need it in your model class, you can put a reference to it there and call [setItems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#setItems-javafx.collections.ObservableList-) on your TableView to sync the data.  If you don't need it in your model class, you can just call getItems() on the TableView and directly manipulate the table data through that.

Comment: Your class would need to extend `Collection` to be able to be passed to one of the `observableArrayList` methods. Even then this will just copy the contents to a new list instead of using your list as backing list. For that to work you'd need to implement `List` and use `observableList`; Note that doing this would result in degraded performance of the `TableView`, since it accesses elements via index and would also mean you'd need to modify the list via the wrapper `ObservableList` only. If you'd want to modify the list via`PropertyModel`,you don't have a choice but implement`ObservableList`.